# Where to store php file on mysql server for android app

Tags: web-services

I'm writing an Android app. Now i want to connect to a database, so i found some old computer which will function as server. I installed MySQL server and Workbench on it. And ofcourse created my database.

I'm searching the whole web for how to write a php webservice, so that's not the problem. But i can't find any explanation of where i have to store the php file on my server computer.

So can anyone help me with this and explain where i have to store/put the php webservice file?

Thanks in advance,

Geert

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to configure Apache server ?

Comment: The www folder? Also, why not just use WAMP or some other such simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a webserver (e.g. Apache) that will listen to requests from browsers and will send to it a requested files. That's needed for downloading such files as HTML or JPG.

When you want to write a PHP webservice, you need also a PHP module which will **interpret** the text in .php file, run it and send its output to a user (instead of sending to a user the contents of a .php file).

Probably [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) / [LAMP](http://lamphowto.com/) will be the best pack including all you need.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I got windows xp on the other computer, and wamp wont run on it, u got any other options? Thanks

Comment: Why not? I think it should. If you're using a 32-bit XP, are you sure that you are downloading 32-bit WAMP?

Comment: yes i'm sure i got the 32bit version, there are 2 different 32-bit versions, i tryed them both, but both not starting.

Comment: I'm gonna try apache webserver now

Comment: apache webserver works, and it sees the mysql database. But now the final question (i hope): where do i put my php webservice?

Comment: Well... I don't want to be impolite, but there are plenty of manuals that describe how to install PHP for Apache.  Google for example: apache install php module